# Horizontal footnotes in a minipage enviornment

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage

I am fairly new to latex and are struggeling to find any solutions to this following problem:

I have a horizontal table, which is filled with observations from other studies. I want to reference the observations in the different columns by using footnotes, which will be listed in a minipage enviornment just below the table. But my problem is that the footnotes are being listed vertically, I want them to be listed horizontally (maby 3 referenes in length) so they fill out the space on the mini page.The simplified image of my table shows this problem   [image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5} % determind line spacing in table
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}% fontsize of footnotes
%\shortstack{text//text} command forces line break in a cell
\begin{minipage}{200mm}% minipage for footnotes

\begin{tabular}{>{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c >{\scriptsize}c }

\shortstack{Column\\1} &
\shortstack{Column\\2} &
\shortstack{Column \\ 3} & 
\shortstack{Column\\ 4}  &
\shortstack{Column \\ 5} & 
\shortstack{Column \\ 6} &
\shortstack{Column\\7} & 
\shortstack{Column\\8} 
 \\ 
            \hline
\shortstack{Event 1\\ (Jan 2009) \footnote{some text 1} \footnote{some text 2}}  & \shortstack{temperate} & present & & \shortstack{at friction \\ intersection}& & &  \\       
            \hline
\shortstack{Event 2 \\ (1991-1997) \footnote{some text 3}} &  & \shortstack{not observed \\ (summer 2004) \footnote{some teaxt 4}} & & \small{-}\\
            \hline
\shortstack{Event 3 \\ (1930s), (early 1970),\\ (2003-2005) \footnote{some text 5}\footnote{some text 6}} & temperate & \shortstack{not present,\\(July 2011) \footnote{some text 7}} & & \small{-} & & &  \\
            \hline
\shortstack{Event 4\\ (early 1980s) \\ (2013-2015) \footnote{some text 8}} & \small{-} & \small{-} & 150m (1990-2010) & not detected  \\
            \hline
\shortstack{Event 5 \footnote{some text 9}\\(valley glacier)} & temperate & \small{-}  \\
            \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in the threeparttable package.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following layout that uses `booktabs` for the fex horizontal lines, `tabularx` for automatic linebreaks in table cells and a table that is automatically as wide as the linewidth. For the "footnotes" I have used the `threeparttable` environment with the `para` option and the `\tnote` command. With this, you table can easily fit into the page without the need to decrease the font to `\scriptsize` and without decreasing the `\arraystretch`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5} % determind line spacing in table
%\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}% fontsize of footnotes
%\shortstack{text//text} command forces line break in a cell
%\begin{minipage}{200mm}% minipage for footnotes
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Column 1 &
Column 2&
Column  3 & 
Column 4  &
Column  5 & 
Column  6 &
Column 7 & 
Column 8 
 \\ 
            \midrule
Event 1 \newline (Jan 2009)\tnote{a}\tnote{b}  & temperate & present & & at friction  intersection & & &  \\  \addlinespace
Event 2  (1991-1997)\tnote{c} &  & not observed  (summer 2004) \tnote{d} & & -- \\
            \addlinespace
Event 3  (1930s), (early 1970), (2003-2005)\tnote{e}\tnote{f} & temperate & not present, (July 2011)\tnote{g} & & -- & & &  \\
         \addlinespace
Event 4 (early 1980s) (2013-2015)\tnote{h} & -- & -- & 150m (1990-2010) & not detected  \\
            \addlinespace
Event 5\tnote{i} (valley glacier) & temperate & --  \\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
%\end{minipage}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] some text 1
\ite**m[b] some text 2
\item[c] some text 3
\item[d] some text 4
\item[e] some text 5
\item[f] some text 6
\item[g] some text 7
\item[h] some text 8
\item[i] some text 9
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```